# Wordpress: CSS issues with centering a horizontal menu and mysterious paddings around menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, padding

I am creating a website with Wordpress for my mother-in-law (that's for the girly design). Basically I am near completion, but I am way over my head with two issues in the CSS. These seem very basic issues even from my standpoint of view, but with hours and hours of tinkering I am fresh out of ideas and Google didn't help me this time. It's been a while since I have had to create or modify any CSS.

First problem:

I cannot get the horizontal menu to center. I have tried to remove the `float:left`, I have tried to replace it with `float:none` and I have changed the `display: block` and `display:inline` lines to inline-blocks but the menu stays in its position. Only difference I have managed to make is to move the whole menu to the top of the page and that's not desired. What could be the issue in this?

Second problem:

There seems to be padding (the white lines) at the top of the menu and at the bottom and top of the small menu (mobile). I have tracked down all the padding-lines in the CSS but none of them really make a difference, only one which removed the horizontal paddings and that's not desired.

I would be really glad if somebody spots where I have gone wrong!

The website is at http://janenlahwr.cluster020.hosting.ovh.net/

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Tero Korhonen
Lappeenranta, Finland

Comment: 1.Firs problem solution, add this
`.main-navigation ul {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: Can you please be precise with second question, I don't understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi! Can you see the thin horizontal white line at the top of the menu? I want to get rid of that. If you resize the windows so the small menu appears, theres a thicker white line at the bottom of the menu as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Tero,

the first problem has really quick solution - *CSS3 Flexbox*. You can read about it [on this w3schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). 
Remove unnecessary `float: left` and add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to `.main-navigation ul`. So it should looks like this:

```
.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Second problem you can fix with setting `div.site-logo` max-height = height your logo (I see that is 200px). So in this case should looks like this:

```
.site-logo {
    min-height: 70px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    line-height: normal;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I forgott check for lower resolutions. There is problem with `overflow`. You set in style.css:640 `overflow: hidden` and it works correctly since resolution is above 800px. If not then activates this rule:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #main {
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```

that overwrites previous correct rule for *#main* `overflow: hidden`. So you have two options: delete this rule for screens over 800px or change this property from visible to hidden.

I hope I helped you with your problems :) Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! This removed the "full menu" bar but if you resize the window (or browse to the site with a mobile phone) so that the "mobile menu" shows, there's still a thick white bar. Have any ideas on that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The white line disappeared. You have been a great help sir!

Answer (score 0):

For the menu problem, change your CSS rules like this:

```
.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    /* remove float: left; */
    text-align: center; /* added */
    width: 100%; /* added */
}
.main-navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    /* remove float: left; */
    text-align: center; /* not necessary */
}
```